# Book recommendations for introductory Bayesian statistics?

Tags: statistics, reference-request, book-recommendation, bayesian

Anyone here have some recommendations for a good book introducing the reader to Bayesian statistics?

Let me mention my background.  My undergraduate majors were in Actuarial Science and Statistics, and I did very well with an *Elementary Probability Theory* course during graduate school.

I am looking towards applying Bayesian theory in card game simulations.  I have tried searching [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Bayesian+book+recommendation), but none of the current recommendations appear to be useful for my present purposes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an introduction, I would recommend Probabilistic Programming & Bayesian Methods for Hackers by Cam Davidson-Pilon, freely available online.

http://camdavidsonpilon.github.io/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers/

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation, @alghamdi!

Answer (score 1):

https://www.bayesrulesbook.com/

Just started reading. So far so good:)

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation, @Raibek!